# Making a GUi for search engine

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, search-engine, whoosh

I am attempting to make a search engine application which can be hosted on the web. 
Currently I have a python code for a search engine (using "[whoosh](http://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html)" if anyone if familiar with it). FOr this we can type in query and it gives some results.

But now I want to make a running search engine application where user can give input and the results are displayed just as the way Google search works. Can someone give some pointers about what application development software/package **(python based)** which can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make a website? Use something like Flask to take in your requests, process them with your Python code and then spit out results accordingly?